# show the different html links details in another single page dynamically

Tags: html, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, html-parsing

i have 7 links in one html page and when i clicking any links leads to another page with link heading(eg: link heading) of that link.

My question is  ,for this instead of creating 7 other pages for 7 links ,is that possible to create a single page which shows the links headings dynamically when the links are clicked?

Is that possible by using xml ?am new to xml parsing ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a programming language such as php to dynamically load the data. Then the links can be like: http://example.com/link.php?target=3